# I want to insert data into my dropdown list from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new on asp.net mvc and i want to insert data to my drop down list from database. Actually i want to fetch countries name from database. Please share your advice.

@html.dropdown

Comment: Pls add code what you have already tried, your country database object, your controller and view that you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must provide data for your dropdown (select) in a controller -> action like this.
I've suppose you have an action called Create and you have a model with **Name** and **Id** properties, so:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var ListData = _db.ListData.ToList();
            ViewBag.List = new SelectList(ListData, "Id", "Name", "0");
            return View();
        }
```

After that you need to use this kind of code for render dropdown (select) element in the cshtml file from provided data (**ViewBag.List**):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.[use a viewModel to set data], (SelectList)ViewBag.List, new {});
```

Comment: glad to hear that, so you can mark it as a correct answer.